# Please set syntax highlighting for google-apps-script tag to JS

Tags: feature-request, tags, syntax-highlighting

Google Apps Script uses JavaScript syntax, so the [`google-apps-script`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) tag should use JS syntax highlighting. Headline from their [homepage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/?hl=en):

> Increase the power of your favorite Google apps — like Calendar, Docs, Drive, Gmail, and Sheets.
>   Apps Script lets you do more with Google. **All on a JavaScript platform in the cloud.**